# groovy list initialization indentation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have a problem with how Eclipse does indentation of a List initialization statement when I use automatic code formatting.

The problem is that if the list is long enough Eclipse folds each value:
hence:

```
def list = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" ]
```

becomes:

```
def list = [
    "aaa",
    "bbb",
    "ccc",
    "ddd",
    "eee"
]
```

as far I understand groovy plugin inherits most of the formatting fro the Java style, but I found no option to control this folding in the Java formatter preferences.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Nice timing.  I just fixed this bug yesterday.

See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1488

If you install the latest snapshot build of groovy-eclipse, and go to Preferences -> Groovy -> Formatter, there is a new option called "Long list length".  Change the value to something larger and lists will not be wrapped until they are at least as long as the value in the box.

See the instructions here to install a snapshot build:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin#EclipsePlugin-DevelopmentBuilds

Comment: thanks for the answer, found the new setting and it works when the list is under that value.

Still when the list is very long it folds to an indentation with one item per line, is there a way to make it fold to a format that splits in multiple lines of the configured lenght instead of single items?

Comment: I could implement that, but could you raise a new issue?  I am trying to fix a bunch of formatting issues for the 2.7.2 release and so I could probably get to it.  In your feature request, please include some samples of how you would like to see things formatted.

Comment: Forgot to mention...the issue tracker is here: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE